# Trying to pass antiforgerytoken in ajax post ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, antiforgerytoken

Hi I'm trying to pass an antiforgerytoken to MVC asp.net from an ajax call, I tried the call on its own and it seems to work, BUT as soon as I have other variables inside the data call with the antiforgerytoken it keeps to fail

I would like to point out that I have the antiforgerytoken form in a partial view, and I would like to use the antiforgerytoken for many forms using ajax

Here is an example of my ajax call

```
var form = $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm');
var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();

function GetStoragePlacesForHome($hid) {
    alert(gettoken());
    $(".storageItemArea").html("");
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $linkUrl + "StoragePlaces/GetStorageByHome",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            __RequestVerificationToken: token,
            hId: $hid,
            uId: $("#uid").val(),
        },
        success: function (resultData) {
            
            }
            $(".totalStorage").text($(".storageItemArea").children().length);
        }
    })
    
}
```

And below is the form I wish to access

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult GetStorageByHome(int hId, string uId)
    {
        Home home = db.Homes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == hId && x.Ownerfk == uId);
        if(home != null)
        {
            List<StoragePlace> storagePlaces = db.StoragePlaces.Where(x => x.HomeId == home.Id).ToList();
            string jsonStoragePlaces = new JsonParser().GenericParser(storagePlaces);
            return Json(new { success = true, jsonStoragePlaces, responseText = "successful." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, responseText = "Error no homes found!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }

    }
```

I have included the antiforgerytoken in headers as well but to no luck, as mentioned before this works when I don't have other variables within the data field inside the ajax call

Comment: I checked and old project where I used **AntiForgeryToken** and your code seems very similar to mine. The only difference that I could noticed is that I got that value like this `var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();` By the way, you have an extra comma in this line `uId: $("#uid").val(),`

Comment: hey thanks for the heads up i doubt that how you got the value would have any difference, tried it just in case but for now luck thanks for the assistance